# Sending collection of data from the view to the controller using data- attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

If I have inside razor view access to collection of data which I want to pass to 
the js function inside separate js file how can I do that?

I tried with

```
<div id="details" data-fields="@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Fields))">
```

and inside js file I have function which should accept this like

```
var model = { Fields: $('#details').data('fields') }
```

but this obviously doesn't work with collections. How would you do this?

My model `Field.cs` contains two simple properties

```
public class Field{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode...` is creating a javascipt array. Why are you trying to send a collection to a view and then send it all back again unchanged?

Comment: I'm receiving collection inside view as part of the model I use on that page.  Now I have some abrstractions inside js function which sits inside separate file where I want to use that collection for further calculations.

Comment: Then assign the collection to a javascript array and pass that variable to the function.

Comment: Thanks. can you please post that as an answer with example?

Comment: You have not given enough details of what your doing to give an answer. For example, in the main view use `var fields = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Fields));` to assign it to a global variable Then in your external file, you can just refer to (say) `$.each(fields, function() {`. And the title still says _pass it from the view to the controller_ which is confusing also (not to an external script), so that confusing also.